# Password-protected build for TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have created a TFS build definition to create our software releases. Now I want to restrict access to start this build. Main goal is to avoid starting a release build by accident. Is there a way to either

- make the build available/visible/startable only to a certain account or
- protect the build definition with a password?

EDIT: finally I came up with an own solution for part 2 of the question

I edited the buildprocesstemplate and added a custom argument ([following this howto](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx)) which I test at the very start of the buildprocess. If one tries to start the build without entering the password, the build will fail with an exception. Of course this is not a supersafe protection by any means, but that was not the intention in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the build definition > `Security` > Select a group you wish to control >

Check the `Deny` permission for:

`Queue builds`

`Edit build definition`

`View build definition`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KMoraz... quick question: How do you prevent other users or groups from changing the Security settings on a build definition?